# How to directly move camera to current location in Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android

Without clicking any button, how to directly get the current location and move the camera to it.
Also, I found that there is a button on the right top of the map. When click on it, it will go to current location. How to get location where it return when clicked that button?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

make sure you have these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then make some activity and register a LocationListener

```
package com.example.location;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class LocationActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements LocationListener     {
private GoogleMap map;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private static final long MIN_TIME = 400;
private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this); //You can also use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER        
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
}
```

map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Thumbs up for removeUpdates().

Comment: what is this SherlockFragmentActivity? It is not mentioned in your answer.

Comment: it's an old support library to back port the actionbar... you can replace that with FragmentActivity

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: You don't need the permission android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: removeupdate() awesome now it is not going to the current location when map updated every x second tanxx

Comment: What are the other methods for? apart from onLocationChanged()

Comment: The docs will do a better job of explaining than I can:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: Using LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER was more accurate than using LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER when I was using this code.

Comment: where do I find the latest dependency for SupportMapFragment etc?

Answer (score 32):

The above answer is not according to what Google Doc Referred for Location Tracking in Google api v2.

I just followed the official tutorial and ended up with this class that is fetching the current location and centring the map on it as soon as i get that.

you can extend this class to have LocationReciever to have periodic Location Update.
I just executed this code on api level 7

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Here it goes.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap map;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
/*
 * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
 * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
 */
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

// Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    // Global field to contain the error dialog
    private Dialog mDialog;

    // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
    public ErrorDialogFragment() {
        super();
        mDialog = null;
    }

    // Set the dialog to display
    public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
        mDialog = dialog;
    }

    // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return mDialog;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map = mapFragment.getMap();

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}

/*
 * Called when the Activity becomes visible.
 */
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    if(isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()){
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

}

/*
 * Called when the Activity is no longer visible.
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

/*
 * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity
 * by Google Play services
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
                int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Decide what to do based on the original request code
    switch (requestCode) {

        case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try
             * to connect again
             */
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    mLocationClient.connect();
                    break;
            }

    }
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode =  GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d("Location Updates", "Google Play services is available.");
        return true;
    } else {
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog( resultCode,
                                                                                                              this,
                                                                                                              CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {
            // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
        }

        return false;
    }
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
 * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
 * request the current location or start periodic updates
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
 * location client drops because of an error.
 */
@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Display the connection status
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
 * Location Services fails.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
            * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
            * PendingIntent
            */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry. Location services not available to you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient  can not be resolve after updating google play service also..

Comment: the answer is 2 years old now. If you can post the new answer. That will be helpful

Comment: I have answered this question with the latest doc. Please check it,

Answer (score 11):

I am explaining, **How to get current location** and **Directly move to the camera to current location** with assuming that you have implemented **map-v2.** For more details, You can refer [official doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial).

Add location service in gradle

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1"
```

Add location permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Make sure you ask for RunTimePermission. I am using [Ask-Permission](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission) for that. Its easy to use.

Now refer below code to get the current location and display it on a map.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices
                .getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

}

private void getDeviceLocation() {
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            Location location = task.getResult();
                            LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                                    location.getLongitude());
                            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM);
                            googleMap.moveCamera(update);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

When user granted location permission call above `getDeviceLocation()` method

```
private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                getDeviceLocation();
            } else {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change moveCamera to animateCamera like below

```
Googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locate, 16F))
```

Answer (score 0):

**My answer is for those ,who are looking for current location zoom animation, when app starts. And to get location of current position.**

Let me know in the comment, if anything is missing.

**Note:-** i **assumes** you already granted all **runtime permission** for location.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
    mMap = googleMap;
    
    getData(mMap);
    animateCamera();


}
```

**getData method returns lat lng of ideal position in the map.So basically at the end camera zoom animation is getting ideal at currunt position.so it gives current position lat lng.**

```
  private void getData(GoogleMap mMap) {

    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {

            LatLng center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            String sLatitude = String.format("%.6f", center.latitude);
            String sLongitude = String.format("%.6f", center.longitude);
            StringBuilder mLatLng = new StringBuilder();
            mLatLng.append(sLatitude);
            mLatLng.append("°");
            mLatLng.append(" ");
            mLatLng.append(sLongitude);
            mLatLng.append("°");
            binding.latLng.setText(mLatLng);

        }
    });

private void animateCamera() {
    Location location = getLastKnownLocation();
    if (location != null) {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        //delay is for after map loaded animation starts
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 15));

            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

**this will returns best location provider**

```
private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            // Found best last known location: %s", l);
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
```