# How can I use Location Services in Google Heatmap?

Tags: android, google-maps, heatmap

I have a Google [heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap) that I want to make aware of users' locations. I want the map to automatically zoom into users' locations.

Currently the map centers on the lat/lon I provide.

```
  //  @Override
  protected void startDemo() {
  getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(34,-118.5), 12));
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to make the heatmap location aware? I have looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756758/how-to-directly-move-camera-to-current-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2), but I haven't been able to make the heatmap location aware. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing I try has been working yet' - have you been able to get any user location at all? It might help to get that working before trying to integrate it into your Heatmap code.

Comment: Yes, I can get user location and it works in one app. Efforts at merging this user location aware app with the heatmap have not been working. I updated my question to be clearer. If I make more progress with the merge, I'll post more code.