# Starting a map with current location

Tags: android, google-maps

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
private void setUpMap() {
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

}

This is my Activity.
I want to start my app with my current location. I looked for some codes but none have the answer that I want. Can someone tell me what I should add?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: You can:
Location location = new Location("");
    location.setLatitude(0.0d);
    location.setLongitude(0.0d);
OR in the same way like you add location to marker:
example: new LatLng(0, 0) (for Lat=0 and Lng=0)

Answer (score 0):

Please use Android's [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to get Lat/Lng with respect to your current services. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227292/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-mobiledevice-in-android) that explains the usage of [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

After getting a [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object from the [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), use the lat/lng to position the map like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756758/how-to-directly-move-camera-to-current-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2).